# How to let awesome window(client) displayed always on visible workspace?

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

As title tell. There is such an option when you right click the blank on nautilus in awesome, then a rectangle will appear in the title and it worked, any short cuts for this function to use on other applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should manage client.sticky property. For example you can add this line

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "s",      function (c) c.sticky = not c.sticky  end),
```

to clientkeys table in your rc file and use "Mod4+s" hotkey to make focused window always visible.

Comment: I wonder why it is not enabled by default